# Add a space after period if one does not exists

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to add a space after any periods that do not have one.

Here's my problem:

I have addresses like:

```
123 W.Redtail Drive
548 N.Smokey Mountain Pass
```

There should be a space after that period, most of the time there is but ~15% of the time it's omitted.

I thought I could just do this but then I realized this would (even it it did work, it would replace that first character with a blank space so this idea is no good.

```
update directory
set ADDR1_CLEANSED = REPLACE(addr1_cleansed,'._','. ')
```

but this does not work, is it possible to accomplish this? Most of the time the space exists so I don't just want to add another one....

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Think about _why_ would you actually want to do that? Address fields are _meant_ to be free form text, and there's also almost certainly a situation where adding the space is the _wrong_ thing to do. It's not as if USPS or UPS or StarTrack won't be able to figure it out without a space. Of course, if it's an anal retentive thing (and look that up before you assume I'm insulting you), I understand, I often get those urges myself :-) But that still doesn't necessarily make it a good idea.

Comment: nasty hack: `replace(replace(addr1_cleansed, '.', '. '), '  ', ' ')`

Comment: @paxiablo - I'm not offended, this table is maybe 50k rows, and is updated by a couple individuals who type and don't validate (over which I have no control).  It's not used for mailings, so yeah, it's more anal.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - That's stupidly simple and will help me sleep tonight.